# How does axios get the tree json and render a vue page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Recently, due to the needs of the vue background management project, the page needs to make an infinite tree.I have return json data of `http://private-4f7c1-zyl1.apiary-mock.com/questions`. Go to the [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/wy8nb1d4/6/).

Return is like this：

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"HuaWei",
    "pid":0
},
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Apple",
    "pid":0
},
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"Iphone X",
    "pid":2
},
{
    "id":4,
    "name":"nove 3",
    "pid":1
},
{
    "id":5,
    "name":"Iphone 8 plus",
    "pid":2
 }
]
```

I have Vue code:

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
phoneList: []
},
mounted() {
   axios.get('https://private-4f7c1-zyl1.apiary-mock.com/questions')
.then(response=> {
  console.log(response);
  this.phoneList = response.data;
})
 .catch(error => {
 console.log(error);
 });
 },
  methods: {
 }
})
```

I can provide an effect HTML template like this:[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/wy8nb1d4/5/).

**I want this effect：**

[image]

Comment: It's not vue related , it' s just some simple algorithm and you'd better take a look at `recursion algorithm`, it'll help you a lot.

Comment: @Jerry I understand, will go see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data structure problem. You could reshape the Axios response into a data structure that facilitates rendering that particular tree:

1. In a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) (e.g., named "phoneGroups"), get all the groups, indicated by `pid` of `0`:

   ```
   const groups = this.phoneList.filter(x => x.pid === 0);
   ```
2. For each group, get the items belonging to that group, indicated by a `pid` that matches the group ID:

   ```
   const data = {};
   for (const g of groups) {
     const subitems = this.phoneList.filter(x => x.pid === g.id);
     data[g.id] = {
       group: g,
       subitems,
     };
   }
   return data;
   ```
3. In the template, render the computed result as follows:

   ```
   <ul>
     <li v-for="({group, subitems}) in phoneGroups" :key="group.id">
       <span>{{group.name}}</span>
       <ol>
         <li v-for="subitem in subitems">-- {{subitem.name}}</li>
       </ol>
     </li>
   </ul>
   ```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ah7xj2q1/)